# Cordova plugin purchase. Approved event does not fire

Tags: android, cordova, subscription

I'm using a plugin https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase to implement a paid subscription in the app. I checked the work of the subscription on Android 5.1.1. And after I called the store.refresh() triggered the update event. But after that the approved event does not fire.

Here is my code

```
function subscriptionIsApproved(product) {
    product.verify();
    console.log("Is approved: " + JSON.stringify(product));
}

function subscriptionIsVerified(product){
    product.finish();
    console.log("Is verified: " + JSON.stringify(product));
}

function subscriptionIsUnverified(){
    createErrorAlert(app,localDictionary[storage.getItem('language')].VERIFICATION_ERROR,null);
    setNotSubscribeMode(app,$$);
    console.log("Subscription is unverified");
}

function subscriptionIsUpdated(product){
    if (!product.owned) {
        store.order(product);
        setNotSubscribeMode(app, $$);
    }else
        setSubscribeMode(app,$$);

    console.log("Is updated: " + JSON.stringify(product));
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    var sbType;//subscription type
    if(Framework7.device.ios)
        sbType = store.NON_RENEWING_SUBSCRIPTION;
    else
        sbType = store.PAID_SUBSCRIPTION;

    store.register({
        id: subscriptionId,
        type: sbType
    });

    console.log("PRODUCT: " + JSON.stringify(store.get(subscriptionId)));

    store.error(function(e){
        console.log("ERROR " + e.code + ": " + e.message);
    });

    if(Framework7.device.ios)
        store.validator = app_store_verification;
    else if(Framework7.device.android)
        store.validator = play_market_verification;

    store.when(subscriptionId).approved(subscriptionIsApproved);
    store.when(subscriptionId).verified(subscriptionIsVerified);
    store.when(subscriptionId).unverified(subscriptionIsUnverified);
    store.when(subscriptionId).updated(subscriptionIsUpdated);
    store.when(subscriptionId).cancelled(function(product){console.log("Is cancelled: " + 
    JSON.stringify(product));});
}

//init purchase by button click
$$(document).on('click','#continueBtn',function(){
    mainView.router.navigate('/confirmPhone/');
    store.refresh();
});
```

It doesn't work. After I press the button and call store.refresh() fires the update event in which I call store.order(product) method that should end with an approved event, but that doesn't work. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I added the cordova-plugin-purchase plugin, and it was necessary cc.fovea.cordova.purchase. Now approved works. But I still get an error: Your order is being processed. The product will be available in a few minutes